# How to solve react.js API error undefined (GET https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/undefined 404)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am getting this such kind of error **undefined** , I am working (movie id and tv show id ) details using redux-toolkit , I know that undefined error is coming in this line

```
`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movieDetails?.poster_path}`
```

DetailsView.js ->page

```
tag:import React from 'react'
import {  useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { css } from "@emotion/react";
import BounceLoader from "react-spinners/BounceLoader";
import DetailViewInfo from "../Componets/DetailViewInfo";
//port Recommendation from "../Componets/Recommendation";
import Navbar from "../Componets/Navbar";
import FnavBar from "../Componets/FnavBar";



const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 20% 50%;
  border-color: red;
`;

const DetailView = () => {
const movieData = useSelector((state) => state.movies)
const  tvshowData = useSelector((state) => state.tvshow)
const {movieId} = useParams();
const { movieDetails, loadingMovie} = movieData;
const {tvshowDetails, loadingTvshow} = tvshowData;

// console.log(movieDetails);
 console.log(movieData);


return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <div style={{marginTop: "100px"}} className="detail-view-wrapper">
        {loadingMovie || loadingTvshow ?(
          <BounceLoader css={override} size={40}/>
        ):(
          <div className="details-view-poster">
             <img
              src={
                movieId
                  ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movieDetails?.poster_path}`
                  : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${tvshowDetails?.poster_path}`
                 
              }
              alt="poster"
            />  
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
        <DetailViewInfo/>
      <h1>DetailsView </h1>
      <FnavBar/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DetailView;
```

movieSlice.js

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { client } from "../App/Api";

const initialState = {
    loadingMovie: false,
    movieDetails: {},
    //cast
    loadingCast: false,
    castDetails: [],
    //recommendation
    loadingRecommendations: false,
    recommendedMovies: [],
    error: "",
};
export const fetchMovieId = (id) => {
    return async(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(setPending())
        try {
            const res = await client.get(`/movie/${id}?language=en-US`)
            const movie = res.data;
            console.log("MovieId:", movie);
            dispatch(setSuccess(movie));
            return movie;
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(setError(error));
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

export const fetchMovieCast = createAsyncThunk('movies/fetchMovieCast',
    async(id) => {
        const res = await client.get(`/movie/${id}/credits?language=en-US`)
        const cast = res.data;
        console.log("movieCastId:", cast);
        return cast;
    })


export const fetchRecommendation = createAsyncThunk('movies/fetchRecommendation',
    async(id, type) => {
        const res = await client.get(`${type}/${id}/similar?language=en-US&page=1`)
        const recommendedMovies = res.data;
        console.log("Recommen:", recommendedMovies);
        return recommendedMovies;
    }
)

export const movieSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'movies',
    initialState,

    reducers: {
        //old movieType
        setPending(state, action) {
            state.loadingMovie = true;
        },
        setSuccess(state, action) {
            state.movieDetails = action.payload;
        },
        setError(state, action) {
            state.error = action.payload;
        }
    },

    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchMovieCast.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.loadingCast = true;
            })
            .addCase(fetchMovieCast.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.loadingCast = false;
                state.castDetails = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(fetchMovieCast.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.error = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(fetchRecommendation.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.loadingRecommendations = true;
            })
            .addCase(fetchRecommendation.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.loadingRecommendations = false;
                state.castDetails = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(fetchRecommendation.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.error = action.payload;
            })
    }

})
export const { setPending, setSuccess, setError } = movieSlice.actions;
export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

Details.js -> comp

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import CastList from "../Componets/CastList";

//slicer
import { fetchMovieCast, fetchMovieId, fetchRecommendation } from "../Redux/MovieSlice";
import { fetchTvshow, fetchTvshowCast } from "../Redux/TvShowSlice";
//icons
import { SiImdb } from "react-icons/si";
import { BsPlayFill, BsLink45Deg } from "react-icons/bs";

const DetailViewInfo = () => {
   const  { movieId,tvshowId } = useParams();
   console.log(tvshowId);
   console.log(movieId);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() =>{
       dispatch(fetchMovieId(movieId));
      //  dispatch(fetchMovieCast(movieId));
       
    },[])

    useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(fetchTvshow(tvshowId));
        // dispatch(fetchTvshowCast(tvshowId));
    },[])
    
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <CastList/> */}
    </div>
  )
}

export default DetailViewInfo;
```

I want to solve this